# a mysql query giving output with 6 duplicate values instead of 1

Tags: mysql, unique

I am having trouble in getting unique result from my query. The query mentioned here displays duplicate values 6 times instead of giving an unique answer. How can I get the result only once?

```
SELECT step1 . * , TIME_FORMAT( step2.insert_time,  '%H:%i:%s' ) AS insert_time, 
 DATE_FORMAT( step2.insert_time, '%d-%b-%Y %h:%i:%s' ) tradate, b.batch_name, 
 a.student_rollno, a.student_name, sf.bif_code, sb.subject_name, s.stream_code, 
 c.class_code, dv.division_code, 
 CONCAT( faculty_fname,  ' ', faculty_lname ) facultyname
FROM csm_batch b, csm_step1 step1
INNER JOIN csm_class c ON c.class_code = ClassID
LEFT JOIN csm_stream s ON s.stream_code = StreamID
LEFT JOIN csm_subject sb ON sb.subject_code = SubjectID
LEFT JOIN csm_subject_bif sf ON sf.bif_code = BifID
LEFT JOIN csm_division dv ON dv.division_code = DivID
LEFT JOIN csm_faculty ad ON ad.faculty_id = FacultyID
INNER JOIN csm_step2 step2 ON step2.SessionID = step1.SessionID
LEFT JOIN csm_student a ON a.student_nfc_code = step2.StudentID
WHERE 0 =0
AND step2.SessionID =  '17f32204f8fe4c'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Have you tried using `SELECT DISTINCT`...

Comment: Reading the query like this is not that easy to understand where the duplicates come from. Can you give us more detailed information, maybe a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) example?

Comment: where is u r table structure?

Comment: Suspect the issue is down to the data. One of your joined tables probably has 6 matching rows where you expect 1. If you try your SQL but bring back all data from all the tables then the offending table might be obvious. As one point though, you may have nothing  to determine which rows are retrieved from table csm_batch it seems. It is confusing to mix up the join syntax as you have done.

Comment: @ Alpay: Trying SELECT DISTINCT has brought the repetition to 3 from 6....